# 2 UICollectionViews synchronisation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am currently working on a calendar view that consists of 2 `UIcollectionViews` and present the same dates in a different ways (day/month view_.

I am introducing synchronisation of the dates when one of the cells is pressed: cell's date is picked, second `UIcollectionView's` cell with appropriate date is found and `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` is fired on the second `collectionView`.

It works fine, but I want to have live synchronisation when user scrolls - in `viewDidScroll` I start the same procedure, which is highly ineffective and laggy.

I've also planned to look for `contentOffset` of one of the `UIcollectionViews`, but the cells have different sizes (according to dates) and both of the offsets are in my opinion uncomparable.

Do you have any suggestions of how can I synchronise those 2 `UICollectionViews`